# Webmaster or site name for auto-generated emails with SMTP

Tags: email, smtp

I currently have site notifications from Expression engine using SMTP. All is working great, except the site name is not appearing in the email. It still says that its from ---@website.com instead of it saying that its from Website name.

Any ideas on how to get this work with SMTP? Is there way to go into the codeigniter email file and manually set this to work?

Any help is much appreciated!